# jquery .load on iframe add overiding css styles

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe

I have tried many different options and nothing seems to work

I have a iframe with many inline css styles that have !important tags I want to overide them after the iframe has loaded

Here is my jquery and my failing jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/VJuyR/

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $('<iframe />').load(function(){
          alert('the iframe is done loading');
          $(".poweredBy").css("display", "none");
    });        
});
```

Comment: I know this is not suggested and I am planning to purchase a account, or maybe one day build something like this but for the time being I want to know how to overide the styles.

Comment: If you really wanna do this, load that page in Javascript, take the whole HTML and stick it in a new object, then re-write the HTML back on your page instead of using the iFrame.  It's not efficient by any means but it never is when you use someone else's site lol

Comment: @Deryck Do you have a example of how I would do this?

Comment: If you want to wait til the weekend I'll get on chat and go over with you Friday night.

Answer (score 0):

Use `iframe` in place of `<iframe />`, also use [contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) to get `iframe content` then  use [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) your `element` like,

```
$('iframe').load(function(){
      alert('the iframe is done loading');
      $(this).contents().find(".poweredBy").css("display", "none");
});
```

**Above** will work on `same domain`, the elements are easily accessible.

**But** according to [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) you will get **permission denied type errors**.

Comment: You cannot modify the contents of an iframe you don't own. That would be cross-site scripting. The solution for this is using a proxy.

Comment: @Dude could you explain this proxy

Comment: The idea of the proxy is to have the iframe request go to your server, while the server will get data from another website. It's probably illegal tho, at least for your case. You should probably read the terms and conditions regarding that. [here](https://github.com/cowboy/php-simple-proxy)